# Where is this geyser?

Tags: identify-this, landmarks, locate-this

A book I bought for my son on volcanoes has a page on geysers.  The geyser in the image below is listed as being Old Faithful in Yellowstone National Park.  I have been fortunate enough to watch Old Faithful many times in my life and I know that the geyser in the picture is *definitely not* Old Faithful.

Which geyser is this, and where is it?  I notice there are palm trees in the background, and so conclude that this isn't even a geyser in Yellowstone.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heh, they've made a simple mistake. It IS Old Faithful, but not the Yellowstone one.  It's the one in Calistoga, California.

http://www.oldfaithfulgeyser.com/

[image]

[Wiki page on Calistoga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calistoga,_California), with image on it.

[Bing image search that shows other angles of the geyser](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=old+faithful+calistoga&FORM=HDRSC2)

Comment: Oh man, that means every geyser shown in that book are actually accidental man-made ones.  The book also shows Fly Geyser.